# QueryRecord unable to write attribute

Tags: apache-nifi

Original FlowFile content (stored as JSON):

```json
[
  {
    "report_date": "20210620",
    "metric_name": "mcf:assistedConversions",
    "metric_value": "0"
  },
  {
    "report_date": "20210620",
    "metric_name": "mcf:lastInteractionConversions",
    "metric_value": "9"
  }
]
```

I want to convert it to AVRO and add additional fields from attributes.

1. *account.view.id* = 187712
2. *utm.marks* = utm_campaign=Beeline_2021&utm_content=banner_320х480&utm_medium=Media&utm_source=ad&utm_term=msc

Using `QueryRecord`:

```sql
SELECT '${account.view.id}' AS account_view_id,
       '${utm.marks}' AS utm_marks,
        *
  FROM FLOWFILE
```

It throws error:

```
 org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: java.sql.SQLException: 
Error while preparing statement [SELECT 
'187712' AS account_view_id,
'utm_campaign=Beeline_2021&utm_content=banner_320х480&utm_medium=Media&utm_source=ad&utm_term=msc' AS utm_marks,
*
FROM FLOWFILE]
```

If I'll remove `'${utm.marks}' AS utm_marks` from SQL script, it will work. But why `QueryRecord` can't parse value from `utm.marks` attribute? Unexpected char or what? `JoltTransform` working fine as well.

How to fix it?

**UPDATE**

`QueryRecord config`
[image: queryrecord]

`AvroRecordSetWritter`
[image: Avro Writer]
`JsonTreeReader`
[image: jsonreader]

Comment: Failed to reproduce. Please share more info about how you have configured  QueryRecord

Comment: Just added configs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error happens because you select for two fields and then you select for everything (*). Instead, you can push your attributes *account.view.id* and *utm.marks* into flow file using *UpdateRecord* and then you can just query for everything using *.
Attaching possible configuration for *UpdateRecord* processor. [image]

Or more dynamic approach: [image]

Comment: Interesting. But I have about 10k same flowfiles with same attributes (just different values) and it works fine. U can try to use 1234567 as `account.view.id` and utm_campaign=michelin_XIN4_winter_2019_RF&utm_content=&utm_medium=cpm&utm_source=adv_programmatic_retarg_suv&utm_term=banner as `utm.marks` and try my script.

Comment: Anyway, suggestion with `UpdateRecord` is good, I forgot about this processor.

Comment: added more dynamic approach

Comment: Thanks, I just implemented this. Now I don't even need a `QueryRecord`, `UpdateRecord` is enough. But `QueryRecord` behaviour is still weird. I noticed this many times.